# With as in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I would like to know if is it possible to use the clause "with as" with a variable and/or in a block begin/end.

My code is

```
WITH EDGE_TMP 
AS 
 (select edge.node_beg_id,edge.node_end_id,prg_massif.longueur,prg_massif.lgvideoupartage,prg_massif.lgsanscable from prg_massif 
 INNER JOIN edge on prg_massif.asset_id=edge.asset_id 
 where prg_massif.lgvideoupartage LIKE '1' OR prg_massif.lgsanscable LIKE '1')
,
journey (TO_TOWN, STEPS,DISTANCE,WAY) 
AS
   (SELECT DISTINCT node_beg_id, 0, 0,  CAST(&&node_begin AS VARCHAR2(2000))
    FROM   EDGE_TMP
    WHERE  node_beg_id = &&node_begin
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT node_end_id, journey.STEPS + 1
    , journey.DISTANCE + EDGE_TMP.longueur,

    CONCAT(CONCAT(journey.WAY,';'), EDGE_TMP.node_end_id

    )
```

It create a string as output separated by a ; but i need to get it back as variable or table do you know how?  I used a concat to retrieve data in a big string. Can i use a table to insert data

,
A need to use the result to proceed more treatment.

Thank you,
mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WITH is a part of an SQL statement only. But if you describe why you need it in pl/sql, we'll can advice you something.

Edit: if you have SQL statement which produces result you need, you can assign it's value to pl/sql variable. There are several methods to do this, simpliest is to use [SELECT INTO statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) (add INTO variable clause into your select).

You can use WITH clause as a part of SELECT INTO statement (at least in not-too-very-old Oracle versions).

Comment: Oracle 12c does allow you to put PL/SQL directly into SQL: http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1.php   Although I'm not sure if that's a good idea here, or what exactly the question means.

Comment: How can I use select into with the with statement ?
INSERT INTO @my_answer
WITH EDGE_TMP 
AS ...

Comment: I just want to retrieve the answer from the WITH AS results to use it

Comment: I figured it out :) thank you a lot, i used a insert into in a new table INSERT INTO new_table

SELECT * FROM (
WITH EDGE_TMP